# Complexity of smart contracts

Tags: contract-development, contract-design

I am trying to estimate the complexity of the smart contracts I employ when later triggered. Assume I have 3 smart contracts:

```
contract con1{
}

contract con2{
}

contract main{
}
```

Assume that `main` triggers `cont2`, and `con2` triggers `con1`. Also assume the complexity of `con1` and `con2` is O(n) and that of `main` is O(1).

When I test my contracts over the Ropsten network. There is no cost for running `main`. Shouldn't it be expensive since it calls `con2` of complexity O(n) which will also call `con1` of complexity O(n) as well? Am I missing something?

Is there a better way to analyze contract complexity? The problem is I do not want to think about it from gas price and gas limits because this is very dependent on the written code.

Comment: If you mean what I think you mean, you are correct. However, you probably made a mistake  in the measurement or in the contract code. For example, a solidity contract does *not* have a complexity. Functions inside the contract have a complexity. You need to post more details to make this post answerable.

Answer (score 1):

The only measurement you should be interested in is gas usage. If you are thinking of writing functions which require minutes (even hours?) to run, then you can forget about Ethereum being the right platform for you. You would run out of gas really quick - there's a maximum gas limit for each transaction.

Your statement about "there is no cost in running `main`" isn't correct. You always pay (gas, even if you get the Ether for free) for running contract functions.

Otherwise, if you really insist, you can calculate function complexity in normal way. If you have a O(n) calling O(n) function (a loop inside a loop), the complexity is O(n^2).